# Почему возникает ошибка во время отправки post запроса с js на asp .net

Tags: javascript, c#

Не получается отправить запрос на бэк, вот мой с# код

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult PostCategories(StringModel stringModel)
{
    var newCategory = new Category
    {
        
        Name = stringModel.name
    };
    _db.Categories.Add(newCategory);
    _db.SaveChanges();
    return Ok();
}
```

И js код

```
function saveNewCategory() {
  const elementToRemove = document.getElementById("AddCategoryForm");
  const inputElement = document.getElementById("inputCategory");
  let inputValue = inputElement.value;
  inputValue = {
    "name": inputValue
   }
  const url = "https://localhost:7242/api/categories";
   console.log(inputValue)
  // Удаляем элемент с формой
  const headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  }
  console.log(fetch(url,{
    method: 'POST',
    
    body:  JSON.stringify(inputValue),
    headers: headers
  }).then(res => {return res.json()}))
  elementToRemove.remove();
  // Устанавливаем обработчик события для кнопки "Add"
  const addButton = document.getElementById("addCategories");
  addButton.onclick = addClick;
}
```

VM442:1 Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
at addProduct.js:68:30
введите сюда код

Почему возникает такая ошибка? но при этом данные добовляются в бд

Все работает, рабочий кода:

```
function saveNewCategory() {
  const elementToRemove = document.getElementById("AddCategoryForm");
  const inputElement = document.getElementById("inputCategory");
  let inputValue = inputElement.value;
  inputValue = {
    "name": inputValue
   }
  const url = "https://localhost:7242/api/categories";
   console.log(inputValue)
  // Удаляем элемент с формой
  const headers = {
    'Accept': "application/json, text/plain, */*",
                'Content-Type': "application/json;charset=utf-8"
  }
  fetch(url,{
    method: 'POST',
    
    body:  JSON.stringify(inputValue),
    headers: headers
  })
  .then(response => {
    if (response.ok) {
      fetchCategories(); // Обновляем список категорий после успешного сохранения
      elementToRemove.remove();
      const addButton = document.getElementById("addCategories");
      addButton.onclick = addClick;
    } else {
      throw new Error('Ошибка при сохранении новой категории');
    }
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.error('Ошибка:', error);
  });
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62728896/4496422

Comment: Что за строчка 68 в файле addProduct.js?

Answer (score 1):

Что это:

```
.then(res => {return res.json()}))
```

Вы **НИЧЕГО** не отправляете:

```
return Ok();
```

Какой `JSON` вы хотите получить?

Comment: Уже все работает, спасибо, и я там отправляю на бек данные...

Comment: @КираКира да, но просто вы ожидаете возврата `json` и парсите его через `await res.json()`, о у вас ничего не возвращается )

Comment: посмотрите код js он и отправляет данные, метод Post по факту вроде ничего не должен отправлять, он наоборот получает данные, чтобы создать запись в бд

Comment: @КираКира, post возвращает response, точнее, может его возвращать